# How to pass php parameters inside blade file using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5.4

I will try to be as clear as possible. I have a table with `ng-repeat` in blade file. 
I want to send parameters to a Laravel function, inside the repeat loop.

Here is the example:

The angular

```
app = angular.module("myApp",[], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

The blade file : `$idVal` needs to be the id from the loop.

```
<tr ng-repeat="rec in recomends" ng-init="recomends = {{ $recomends }}">
  <td ><% $index + 1 %></td>
  <td><% rec.name %></td>
  <td>{{ HelperAdmin::getTotalParam('quality',$idVal) }}</td>
</tr>
```

The laravel Function:

```
public static function getTotalParam($field,$reco_id){

    $total = DB::select("SELECT AVG($field) AS mysum FROM recommendation_measure WHERE reco_id = $reco_id ");

    return number_format($total[0] ->mysum,2);
}
```

I need to push `$idVal` as the id of the loop data. But I can't find a way to send it. Any idea?

Hope this question is clear.

Comment: You are mixing Blade with Angular and expecting to parse it in browser.  
You should send $idVal using Angular.

Comment: It can't be working togther somehow?

Comment: You could may be in another way. However it be would a lot better practice to send data via JSON from a different URL than, trying to mix PHP with Angular code.